# Having a view wrap around another view

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way to make my textview wrap around other views? For example in the picture, is there a way to get it to wrap to the edge once it gets below the imageview?

[image]

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
android:background="@android:color/white">


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/AUTHOR_TITLE"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="True">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="Author Name"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:layout_below="@id/AUTHOR_TITLE">


            <ImageView android:id="@+id/PICTURE"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="True"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="True"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/DESCRIPTION" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/PICTURE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF OMGTESTLOLWTF
OMGTESTLOLWTF "/>   
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm really surprised that no one's done this yet =\ Sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the built in widgets.  You can roll your own, it shouldn't be too hard.  You'd need to extend one of the `ViewGroup` classes and add the images and text to that.  Then, in `onLayout()` you can figure out how to flow the text so that it wraps the images.

Comment: Can you actually do this without changing the code of TextView?

Answer (score 0):

Check this library. FlowTextView
https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView