# Wrap a text around an image in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to achieve something like this in Android Studio:

[image]

So far, this is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E9C590"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="131dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pizza_picture" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logoName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/oswald_medium"
        android:text="@string/pizzastic"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#682C20"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Preferably, I'd have to use only a Linear Layout, and this is positioned at the top-center of the screen. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Technically a duplicate of [Having a view wrap around another view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3904064/295004) and Android views are still limited to rectangular shapes in 2024. For possible solutions see: [Draw Curved Text on Canvas with different length of Text in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43464598/295004)

Comment: You'd need to create a custom view for this.  There's nothing built into Android that does curved text.